# VB.net: How to add different multipliers together?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, multiplication, addition

I am creating an EXP multiplier and I do not know how to separate multipliers.

My Aim:
My aim is to make it so that the multiplier from 'checkbox5.checked = true' will not multiply by the rest of checkboxes but just add its product.
If 'checkbox1.checked = true' it will multiply the EXP, which is the input amount by 2. So if checkbox4 is checked, it will multiply the EXP by 1.5 again. So 2x1.5 = 3

However for checkbox5, which multiplier is x1.1, I do not want it to be multiplying the rest of the exp, which means 2x1.5x1.1 = 3.3 but rather adding it in separately, but still displaying the answer in one result which i mean is 2x1.5 + 1.1 = 4.1.

So it means if the input is '2' and checkbox 1,4 and 5 is checked then the answer will be 8.2 not 6.6.

But i do not know how to that, please help!

Here is my code:

```
Dim exp2 As Double
Dim exptotal As Double
Dim exp As Double
If IsNumeric(TextBox9.Text) Then
    exp = CDbl(TextBox9.Text)
    exp2 = CDbl(TextBox9.Text)
Else
    MsgBox("Please input a number.")
End If
If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
    exp = exp * 2
End If
If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
    exp = exp * 1.5
End If
If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
    exp = exp * 1.3
End If
If CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
    exp = exp * 1.5
End If
If CheckBox5.Checked = True Then
    exp2 = exp + (exp2 * 1.1)
End If

exptotal = exp + exp2

If exp <> 0 Then
    Label37.Text = totalexp
End If
```

Please help!!

Comment: what is the problem in that,in your style of coding just add the if condition for the three of checkboxes and provide the multiplication function.also bring that if condition as first one.

Comment: but i do not know how to do that, can you help me? i do not understand. can you provide an example?

Comment: add like this `if checkbox1.checked and checkbox3.checked and checkbox5.checked then your condtiton` also do it before all the other condition as also provide exit function in the if statement so that it will not execute other conditons.

Comment: But what condition do i put in for checkbox5 if i do not want it to multiply with the others?

Comment: if all the checkboxes are checked it will not enter in the checkbox5 condition,it will not execute.

Comment: but i want it to execute, just that it will not multiply AGAIN with the others, but it will add. is it possible?

Comment: sorry i dont understand you, can u explain it to me further? so sorry!

Comment: brother as per your code,you will get exp2 as 8.2 anyway if input is 2 and  checkbox 1,4,5 are ticked.please check your calculation.

Comment: no i dont get 8.2 which is why i need help.

Comment: as per ur calculation if `exp`=2 and checkbox 1,4,5 are checked, at first condition `exp=2*2 ie 4` then in checkbox4 condition `exp=4*1.5 ie 6`.now in checkbox5 `exp2=6+(2*1.1) ie 8.2`. did i calculate wrong?

Comment: yes, it is supposed to be like that, but my code has something wrong and i do not know how to fix it. maybe you can help?

Comment: bro i have run and tested your code,its working fine and you get `exp2=8.2 `  and `exp=6` and `exptotal=14.2` for input 2.

Comment: if it gives you wrong,the one possibility is that you may have made mistake in checkbox names.to check that break and see which all conditions executes.

Comment: bro, i realized something. i want `exptotal=8.2` not 14.2, i want     `exp=6` + `exp2=2.2`  because i still have more checkboxes to add in. ANy ways to do this? because i want to add in checkbox6 later which have different multiplier to add into exp2 so it can separate between multiplying and adding in.

Comment: then in checkbox5 condition give `exp2 =  (exp2 * 1.1)`,you will get desired value.else add another condition `if checkbox1.checked and checkbox3.checked and checkbox5.checked then exp=((exp*2)*1.5) (exp2=exp2*1.1)`.it should be before all the other conditions.

Comment: brother, here is my code http://pastebin.com/mQ0650hR but now when i tick only checkbox1 and checkbox2, i don't get 6 anymore i get 8, very confused. Any ideas? please help

Comment: yes you will surely get 8 for `exptotal` with this code.bro you are adding two values to get `exptotal` and you know that even if there is no other conditions exp2 is 2.then how wiill u get 6?

Comment: but it should be 6, what do i need to change?