# VB.net: How to make original variable value fulfill 2 statements?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, multiplication, addition

I am creating an EXP multiplier and I do not know how to make the original variable do be separated to do fulfill 2 statements.

Aim:
I want it so that when `checkbox1.checked = true` `checkbox2.checked = true` `checkbox5.checked = true`, and the `input = 2`, then the answer will be `2 x 2x1.5` + `2 x 1.1` `= 8.2` NOT `2 x 2x1.5x1.1` which gives me `6.6`.

However, I tried using the separator to separate them, then add them together in the result as `exptotal`, but I made a mistake using `exp2` with `exp` as inputs, as the answer is now `2 x 2x1.5` + `2` + `2 x 1.1` as my code writes `exp + exp2` and `exp2 is also an input` so the result is now `8.2` instead of `6.2` with that extra input.

I do not know how to get around so that i can use the ORIGINAL `exp` such that `exp2 = (exp * 1.1)` without using the `exp` from `checkbox1` and `checkbox2`

My code:

```
dim exp as double
dim exp2 as double
dim exptotal as double
If IsNumeric(TextBox9.Text) Then
        exp = CDbl(TextBox9.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("Please input a number.")
    End If
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        exp = exp * 2
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        exp = exp * 1.5
    End If
    If CheckBox5.Checked = True Then
        exp2 = exp2 * 1.1
    End If

    exptotal = exp + exp2
```

This code makes the result includes the input `2` again as `totalexp = exp + exp2` which is not what I want. I want to get rid of that extra input but still having the `checkbox5` statement being ADDED together with `checkbox1` and `checkbox2` NOT multiplied. But I do not know how to do that. This is the closest I can come to. I hope you can understand me!

I am very confused right now, please help!!

Comment: How is this significantly different than your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30726319/1070452)?

Comment: I don't quite understand what is wrong. This should return exp*2*1.5 + exp2*1.1 when everything is true. Is this not what you want?

Comment: No, this is as close as I can get to my answer, this is adding two values to get `exptotal` however I realized  what I am doing since the last question and I want to phrase it better since there is no solution to my last question. So this is what I want to do `exp*2*1.5 + exp2*1.1` gives me `10.2` but i want it to be `8.2`, i do not want to add two values, but only add one, but i do not know how to do that and this is the closest i can come to. I want to use only the first value to get the 1.1 if the input is 2 but not multiply with the others, but it seems i cant do it.

Comment: I know it is because even if there is no other conditions `exp2` is `2` that is why i have an extra 2 over there, but how do i get rid of the extra `2` that is in `10.2` so that i can get `8.2` if the input is `2`? I want to use the first value only, but I do not know how to do it. Please help me!

Comment: You're over-writing your input variable.... That's why your answer is not as you expect. Try `Dim expInput As Double = CDbl(TextBox9.Text)` and then `exp = expInput * 2`, `exp = exp * 1.5` and `exp2 = expInput * 1.1`. Once you have overwritten a variable, you can't get it's previous value back.

Comment: Hi Sean, but if `checkbox1.checked = false` and if `checkbox5.checked = false` too, the result has an error and will not be changed. If i check one i would still want the others to be calculated as per normal. Any help on this?

Comment: Use more if-statements if your logic is that complicated. You have given us a mathematical equation including brackets in the right place that works. So just split it out. Every time you say "if" to yourself, put an if statement in. If you need more variables to store numbers and add them in later, use them... I'm really struggling to understand where your problem is. I (or anyone else on this site) will not write your logic or calculations for you.

Comment: I re-read the question to see if I couldn't even solve it if I wanted to as the expected inputs and outputs you have given us contradict each other. You want to use an `If...Else If...Else` construct here in combination with some `And` or `Or` logical operators... I think. [If...Then..Else documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) and [Logical and Bitwise operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx)

Comment: My problem is that I want to have this input, which is calculated to be the result. Through this calculation, there will be 2 separate parts, if this segment of checkboxes are checked, the input will be multiplied throughout all checkboxes conditions which is checked. Then there is another segment which uses this input, however this segment multiplies the input and then adds it together with other multipliers. Then the result is both segments added together. `However`, I cannot seem to make the 2nd segment use the input without getting more breaking the whole logic. Hope I can be helped

Comment: You can't be helped if you don't listen and actually try peoples' suggestions. If you need an input variable to be unaffected by other calculations, don't then over-write that input variable with the result of the calculation. Just introduce another variable and don't over-write the original input variable. You could even use the conversion from the text box. Then as far as "if this segment of checkboxes are checked" goes, combine logical operators in your if-statement e.g. `If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox2.Checked = True Then` etc.

Comment: Hi Sean, I have edited my code and what I actually want, as clear as possible, is for `exp2` to use the value of `exp` keyed in Before the calculation in Checkbox1, without duplicating the value that results in an extra input added in.

Comment: Ok thanks Sean, I will try it out now, I think I realized what I was missing out.

Comment: Hi Sean, if I use the And operator, like you said `If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox2.Checked = True Then`... I cannot separate the different conditions that happen if one checkbox is not ticked. As if the checkbox is not ticked, I want the condition to have zero effect on the result.

Comment: Then why do you have the condition there in the first place?

Comment: I have them separated so that if `checkbox1.checked = true` then checkbox1's condition will execute, otherwise it will not have any effect in the calculation. `checkbox2.checked = true then input*1.5` so if `all checkbox.checked = true`, and the input is 3, then the calculation will be (3*2)*1.5+(2*1.1). Else if `checkbox1.checked = false` then (3*2) will be taken out but checkbox2's and 5 condition will still be executed (3*1.5)+(3*1.1) likewise for other conditions. Checkbox5 is from the 2nd segment, which does not continue multiplying from the results but multiplies the input then adds up

Comment: You can separate the conditions. Just do it like `If Condition1 = True And Condition2 = True And Condition3 = True Then ..... Else If Condition2 = True And Condition3 = True Then...` or nest the if conditions (put them inside the previous condition's block): `If Condition1 = True Then exp = calculation1 If Condition2 = True Then exp = calculation2 End If End If`

Comment: really sorry, dont get what you mean by nesting the conditions, can you explain it to me?

Comment: i am trying to separate the conditions right now, will update the results

Comment: @pleasega Can you try to use the variable names in a comment and explicitly explain what you want done:

For example:
A = exp1
B = exp2

IF so and so Then A = A * 2 otherwise B = B*1.15 etc. Then it will be easy to create the logic

Comment: I THINK I GOT IT, i used `If Condition1 = True And Condition2 = True And Condition3 = True Then ..... Else If Condition2 = True And Condition3 = True Then...`, which is easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question is soo confusing. Your variable also don't tell any story, what is CheckBox1, TextBox9 ? These are bad variable name.

Since your not telling what the logic should be but only talk about one scenario, I have to guess.

```
Dim input, total As Double

total = 0

If Not Double.TryParse(TextBox9, input) then
    MessageBox.Show("Please input a number.")
Else
    Dim part1, part2 As Double

    part1 = 0
    part2 = 0

    If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        part1 = 3
    Else If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        part1 = 2
    Else If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        part1 = 1.5
    End If

    If CheckBox5.Checked = True Then
        part2 = 1.1
    End If

    total = (input * part1) + (input * part2)
End If
```